# error foto en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema con el despliegue de las fotos en mi programa web esta construido este sistema en laravel 5.5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se muestran las fotos inspeccione la pag y me sale este error no se a que se debe.a lo mejor es un detalle pero no lo veo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca el codigo

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">



@if(Session::has('Mensaje')){{
    Session::get('Mensaje')
}}
@endif



<a href="{{ url('empleados/create') }}" class="btn btn-success">Agregar Empleado</a>
<br/>
<br/>

<table class="table table-light table-hover">

   <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Foto</th>
    <th>Rut</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Fecha de nacimiento</th>
    <th>Cargo</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>




    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    @foreach($empleados as $empleado)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
        <td>

       <img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$empleado->Foto}}" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" alt="" width="100"> 

        </td>
        <td>{{$empleado->Rut}}</td>
        <td>{{$empleado->Nombre}} {{$empleado->Apellido}}</td>
        <td>{{$empleado->Fecha}}</td>
        <td>{{$empleado->Cargo}}</td>
        <td>

        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ url('/empleados/'.$empleado->id.'/edit') }}">
        Editar
        </a>
        <form method="post" action="{{ url('/empleados/'.$empleado->id) }}" style="display:inline">
        {{csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('¿Borrar?');" >Borrar</button>


        </form>
         </td>

        </tr>

    @endforeach

</tbody>

</table>
</div>
@endsection
```

El programa funcionaba correctamente de la noche a la mañana se hecho a perder creo que debe estar algo malo en la ruta de la foto pero he probado hartas soluciones y no se que error tiene gracias por su tiempo y por leer

Comment: Hola, bienvenido; no es recomendable tratar de resolver dos o más dudas en una misma pregunta, por favor edita esta para dejar solo un problema y crea una nueva pregunta para el otro, será más fácil que obtengas respuestas.

Comment: Dónde tienes almacenado el archivo de la foto y cómo se llama? Que te devuelve `{{ asset('storage').'/'.$empleado->Foto}}`? En la captura de pantalla del error no se vé...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo esto

```
src="{{ asset('storage/'.$empleado->Foto)}}"
```